# Keeping the loop running to check for multiple conditions - Java

Tags: java, loops

I have an array with integers inside it. I want to iterate through them to check if its divisible by 2, 3, 5. At the moment my code only run once.

So say if I have 6 in the list. It will only return "6 is divisible by 2" where it should be "6 is divisible by 2 and 3"

So how do I make the code more elegant. Is there a way to write the code without having to define like `if (number % 2 == 0) && (number % 3 == 0)...` or it has to be done that way? defining each of the condition each time.

this is my code

```
public class checkingDivisibility {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21};
        for (int x : list) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 2 possible");
            } else if (x % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 3 possible");
            } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 5 possible");
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `else` clauses so the `if`s evaluate independently.

Comment: Handy tip: **First, make the code work.**  Then, and _only then_, worry about making it "elegant".

Comment: thanks for the input @KevinAnderson noted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an `else if` after the `if`, which means that the next `if` condition is evaluated only if the first one was `false`. This is not what you want.

What you want is, that each condition should be checked. Hence, you do not need `else if` statements, but only independent `if`s.
Try this..

```
public class checkingDivisibility {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21};
        for (int x : list) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 2 possible");
            } 
            if (x % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 3 possible");
            }  
            if (x % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "div by 5 possible");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would be much more helpful for OP.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a single if-else if... condition use separate conditions :

```
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 2 possible");
        }
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 3 possible");
        } 
        if (x % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 5 possible");
        }
```

This way all three conditions will be evaluated in each iteration of the loop.

Of course you'll need to do something smarter if you want an output like `6 is divisible by 2 and 3`. You can achieve this with a boolean variable.

```
        boolean divFound = false;
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            divFound = true;
            System.out.print(x + "is divisible by 2");
        }
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            if (!divFound) {
                System.out.print(x + "is divisible by 3");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" and 3");
                divFound = true;
            }
        } 
        if (x % 5 == 0) {
            if (!divFound) {
                System.out.print(x + "is divisible by 5");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" and 5");
                divFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (divFound) {
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Why is this more efficient? This one will always do 3 condition checks one after the other. The original one will only do one in the best case, 3 in the worst.

Comment: @Achilles did you read the question. The OP specifically asks for this.

Comment: Ahh I see, yup it worked. Is my thinking correct, so say its in an index where it has the element `6` then with just `if` it will try to match all the conditions? where with `else if` only the first suited condition will be use and the other condition is disregarded?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (x % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 2 possible");
        }
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 3 possible");
        } 
        if (x % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + "div by 5 possible");
        }
```

You get the following:

2div by 2 possible
3div by 3 possible
6div by 2 possible
6div by 3 possible
8div by 2 possible
10div by 2 possible
10div by 5 possible
12div by 2 possible
12div by 3 possible
14div by 2 possible
15div by 3 possible
15div by 5 possible
21div by 3 possible

I think it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using if...else if which means if first condition is met then it will not look second condition. Same for further conditions.
Beacuse of that your output only shows "divisible by 2" as it only checks first condition and never goes on second or further.

So, you sholuld use if on all conditions if you want to check all conditions.